# git clone or pull of a huge repo over slow network ends in fatal EOF

Tags: git, clone, eof

I have a remote repo which is over 2 GB(1 main branch). I have a ADSL broadband connection with around 2-4 MbPS link. I tried to clone the repo.
However i get the following error:
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: early EOF
fatal: index-pack failed

I searched in Stack Overflow and else where and tried to clone a bare repo.
Later I tried to fetch incrementally(I need all the revisions).
Again it fails with similar error as for cloning.

I tried cloning from a Fiber broadband link in office and it seems to work well.
I suspect some timeout issue with git. Can you please help me resolve this?

Update: The repo supports only https and no ssh.

Thanks,
Srinivasa Pradeep

Comment: Do you also drop other large downloads from sources other than Git?  If so, then Git isn't the problem and you should research on your connection.

Comment: I have downloaded close to 1 gb from other websites over https. They take time but eventually complete

Comment: I had the same problem once. My file was around 1 and half GB. As one of friend suggested I tried to pull with **GIT DESKTOP** and it worked for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [git bundle](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Bundling) to "bundle" repository into a single file and get it over http server that can resume interrupted downloads.

Comment: Yesterday I was going through this link https://github.community/t5/How-to-use-Git-and-GitHub/use-git-bundle-in-slow-network/td-p/2282. And I was able to upload the bundle and get the same to the target computer over ftp. I only wanted to add that once you create the clone from the bundle on the target computer, you may want to also set the url of the remote, if you want to push or pull  changes from now on. I did git remote set-url origin <remote repo url>

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the number of processor cores on the workstation which does the clone, the situation might improve with With Git 2.29 (Q4 2020).

Long ago, only 3 threads were used by default when running the `index-pack` task in parallel: that has been adjusted a bit upwards.

See [commit fbff95b](https://github.com/git/git/commit/fbff95b67f7e7bfc8799c2d6d16263cfeb61bc6f), [commit 218389b](https://github.com/git/git/commit/218389b9f3d1b5c8583cc0e944692f7c66af8a03), [commit 4727425](https://github.com/git/git/commit/47274251a4fa15846644f3a3cb9f2fae1fcea644) (21 Aug 2020) by [Jeff King (`peff`)](https://github.com/peff).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 53015c9](https://github.com/git/git/commit/53015c9dd40e0a5afc14aeeb6e6def25f10fff4d), 31 Aug 2020)</sup>

> ### [`index-pack`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/fbff95b67f7e7bfc8799c2d6d16263cfeb61bc6f): adjust default threading cap
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Jeff King</sup>

> Commit [b8a2486f15](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b8a2486f1524947f232f657e9f2ebf44e3e7a243) ("`index-pack`: support multithreaded delta resolving", 2012-05-06, Git v1.7.11-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/cc13431a49800a6a1d2b7ff0b94f67da0fecdbab)) describes an experiment that shows that setting the number of threads for index-pack higher than 3 does not help.
>
> I repeated that experiment using a more modern version of Git and a more modern CPU and got different results.
>
> Here are timings for p5302 against `linux.git` run on my laptop, a Core i9-9880H with 8 cores plus hyperthreading (so online-cpus returns 16):
>
> ```
> 5302.3: index-pack 0 threads                   256.28(253.41+2.79)
> 5302.4: index-pack 1 threads                   257.03(254.03+2.91)
> 5302.5: index-pack 2 threads                   149.39(268.34+3.06)
> 5302.6: index-pack 4 threads                   94.96(294.10+3.23)
> 5302.7: index-pack 8 threads                   68.12(339.26+3.89)
> 5302.8: index-pack 16 threads                  70.90(655.03+7.21)
> 5302.9: index-pack default number of threads   116.91(290.05+3.21)
> ```
>
> You can see that wall-clock times continue to improve dramatically up to the number of cores, but bumping beyond that (into hyperthreading territory) does not help (and in fact hurts a little).
>
> Here's the same experiment on a machine with dual Xeon 6230's, totaling 40 cores (80 with hyperthreading):
>
> ```
> 5302.3: index-pack 0 threads                    310.04(302.73+6.90)
> 5302.4: index-pack 1 threads                    310.55(302.68+7.40)
> 5302.5: index-pack 2 threads                    178.17(304.89+8.20)
> 5302.6: index-pack 5 threads                    99.53(315.54+9.56)
> 5302.7: index-pack 10 threads                   72.80(327.37+12.79)
> 5302.8: index-pack 20 threads                   60.68(357.74+21.66)
> 5302.9: index-pack 40 threads                   58.07(454.44+67.96)
> 5302.10: index-pack 80 threads                  59.81(720.45+334.52)
> 5302.11: index-pack default number of threads   134.18(309.32+7.98)
> ```
>
> The results are similar; things stop improving at 40 threads.
>
> Curiously, going from 20 to 40 really doesn't help much, either (and increases CPU time considerably).
> So that may represent an actual barrier to parallelism, where we lose out due to context-switching and loss of cache locality, but don't reap the wall-clock benefits due to contention of our coarse-grained locks.
>
> So what's a good default value?
>
> It's clear that the current cap of 3 is too low; our default values are 42% and 57% slower than the best times on each machine.
> The results on the 40-core machine imply that 20 threads is an actual barrier regardless of the number of cores, so we'll take that as a maximum.
> We get the best results on these machines at half of the online-cpus value. That's presumably a result of the hyperthreading. That's common on multi-core Intel processors, but not necessarily elsewhere.
> But if we take it as an assumption, we can perform optimally on hyperthreaded machines and still do much better than the status quo on other machines, as long as we never half below the current value of 3.
>
> So that's what this patch does.

Comment: can you clarify how does this relate to problem OP is having? is there some reason to believe increasing threads would help with low bandwidth network?

Comment: @eis increasing the number of cores used by `index-pack` (which is involved, on the client side, by a `git clone`) will decrease the chance to get, as seen by the OP, "`index-pack failed`". Because `index-pack` will be quicker to complete, avoiding any timeout.

Comment: ok. I guess if I'm reading this correctly, this would improve things only if you have more than 6 cores on the computer, as the default is 3 and half the amount of cores was the optimum.

Comment: @eis yes, and with the latest AMD processors, more than 6 cores is starting to be the default offering.